# How to make ajax call for div update wait until its completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I using fusion chart so in fusion chart link events I have Following code

```
if (eventObject.eventType == "linkeditemopened") {
   var url = "/" + $("#appName").val() + "/reports/getUserFilter?isSelectedLegends=true&isSelected=false&isDuplicateReq=true"          
   $('#legendListIdDiv').load(url);
   loadMultiselectDropdown()
}
```

and loadMultiselectDropdown() method below

```
function loadMultiselectDropdown(){
    alert('called load mil')
    var filterList1= $("#updatedlegendListId").val();
    var filterList= $("#legendListId").val();
    alert('type-- '+typeof filterList)
    console.log('filterList1-- '+filterList)
    alert('type-- '+typeof filterList1)
    console.log('filterList1-- '+filterList1)
    var filterList= $("#legendListId").val();
    if(!filterList1 == ''){
        $("#impact-report-user-filter-dropdown-div").show();
        $("#impact-report-user-filter-dropdown").multiselect({ 
              noneSelectedText: 'Select Legends',
              selectedText: '# Legends Selected'
        });
        for(f in filterList1){
            $('#impact-report-user-filter-dropdown').append($('<option>', {
                 value: filterList[f],
                 text:  filterList[f]
            }));
        }
        $("#impact-report-user-filter-dropdown").multiselect("refresh"); 
    }
}
```

But at line `console.log('filterList1-- '+filterList1)` im getting undefined instead of some values as string.

here is dom

```
`<div id="legendListIdDiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="updatedlegendList" id="updatedlegendListId" value="Hyderabad Factory,Delhi Registered Office,Mumbai Warehouse,Bangalore Development Centre,">
</div>`
```

and why? I guess its because ajax is not completed before execution of `var filterList1= $("#updatedlegendListId").val();` line

How to overcome?

Answer (score 2):

Call `loadMultiselectDropdown()` as the callback for `load()`:

```
if (eventObject.eventType == "linkeditemopened") {
   var url = "/" + $("#appName").val() + "/reports/getUserFilter?isSelectedLegends=true&isSelected=false&isDuplicateReq=true"          
   $('#legendListIdDiv').load(url,loadMultiselectDropdown);
}
```

Ajax requests are asynchronous, so you somehow have to wait for it to end to be able to use the results. In your code, you call `loadMultiselectDropdown()` immediately after you make the call, which means the request results are not ready by the time you call `loadMultiselectDropdown()`.